# How to create a new column selecting information from an existing one with .find() (or an alternative to find) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, find

'I need to create a new column selecting concrete information from an existing column. In this case, I want to create a new column called 'name' selecting only the names from the 'id_name' column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'id': [234235, 543, 34234],
      'id_name': ['234235nombre: Paco_ID','543nombre: Lucia_ID','34234nombre:Marta_ID'],
      'age': [35, 29, 40]}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
df

     id          id_name           age
0   234235  234235nombre: Paco_ID   35
1   543     543nombre: Lucia_ID     29
2   34234   34234nombre:Marta_ID    40


df['name'] = df['id_name'].find("nombre: ")+8:df[id_name].find("_ID")

  File "<ipython-input-34-4e5aa874634b>", line 1
     df['name'] = (df[id_name].find("nombre: ")+8):(df[id_name].find("_ID"))
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect as output the following table:

```
     id          id_name           age   name
0   234235  234235nombre: Paco_ID   35   Paco
1   543     543nombre: Lucia_ID     29   Lucia
2   34234   34234nombre:Marta_ID    40   Marta
```

**SOLVED!!!!!! (thanks rommy):**

```
df['name']=df.id_name.str.split(':').str[1].str.split('_').str[0]
```

**I ALSO NEED AN ALTERNATIVE FOR INTEGERS.** Does anyone know how can I create a new column called 'new_hour' extracting the hours from the column 'time' with the following new input?

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'time': ['[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"12"...','[{"nexthour":"05:00","postCount":"3"...'],
   'age': [35, 29]}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Actual output:

```
                   time                     age
0   [{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"12"...     35
1   [{"nexthour":"05:00","postCount":"3"...  29
```

The code should be something like this but it doesn't work:

```
df['new_hour'] = df.time.str.split('"hour":').str[1].str.split('"').str[0]
df.head()
```

Desired output:

```
                   time                     age  new_hour
0   [{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"12"...     35   00:00
1   [{"nexthour":"05:00","postCount":"3"...  29   05:00
```

Comment: `df[id_name]...` did you mean `df['id_name']`?

Comment: The SyntaxError is due to the colon between the two find statements. To use the `find` method use series.str.find() - [String handling (in the documentation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling)

Comment: *I ALSO NEED AN ALTERNATIVE FOR INTEGERS*  - the rule on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).  If your original question is answered correctly, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) the correct answer, and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['name']=df.id_name.str.split(':').str[1].str.split('_').str[0]
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation. Also, have a look here for help to get your posts more readable: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks! Can you look at the new edit to help me solve another related issue, please?

Comment: This should work , df['new_hour']=df.time.str.split('":').str[1].str.split(',').str[0].str.replace('"','')

Comment: The solution you propose is not completely working since you keep the space before the name

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex approach would work better. Something like this:

```
df['name'] = df['id_name'].str.extract(".*nombre:\s?([A-Z][a-z]+)_ID")
```

- `.*nombre:\s?` matches anything followed by nombre and an optional whitespace
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` matches a word with a capital letter (lowercase after)
- `_ID`: ends with _ID

The parentheses specify the part you want to extract.